# Adding Array to JSON using Powershell

Tags: json, azure, powershell

I'm trying to set a JSON file using powershell, but the vm's keep appearing in seperate lines.

This is the code I use:

```
$arrayRg = "VmResGrp"
$vms = vmname
$arrayvms = @(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $arrayRg  | ? {$_.Name -like "*$vms*"}) | select Name 

$data = Get-Content -Path "$updatepath\$encryptParam" -raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$data.parameters.recoveryServicesVaultName.value = "rsvname01"
$data.parameters.recoveryServicesVaultBackupPolicyName.value ="defaultPolicy"
$data.parameters.recoveryServicesVaultResourceGroup.value = "rg-rsvgrp"
$data.parameters.VMNames.value = [array]$arrayvms

$data | ConvertTo-Json -Depth 9 | % { [System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex]::Unescape($_) } |set-content -Path  "$updatedpath\$encryptParam"
```

The output I get is:

```
"VMNames":  {
     "value":  [
       {
        "Name":  "vmr1ssr1"
       },
       {
           "Name":  "vmr1ssr2"
       },
       {
           "Name":  "vmr1ssr3"
       }
    ]
 }
```

What I'm trying to get is:

```
"VMNames":  {
     "value":  [
       {
         "vmr1ssr1"
         "vmr1ssr2"
         "vmr1ssr3"
       }
    ]
 }
```

I've tried using `-expandProperty` on line 3 after `select Name` but this gives me no output on the values at all.

Can anyone see where I'm going wrong?

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: JSON formatting is [name/value pairs](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_syntax.asp).  Your actual output is working as expected.  Are you trying to follow proper JSON notation, or do you want your own proprietary-style format instead?

Comment: @gravitymixes Thanks for your reply, the question where what I'm trying to achieve is incorrectly formatted. For an array, it should be `vmnames: { "value [ **Values** ] },` I believe this is standard, uless I;'m mistaken, although that's also very likely.

Comment: That is not standard JSON formatting.  If you genuinely want the output to look like that, you'd have to design a special parser, and it wouldn't be capable of being interpreted by JSON-standard-specific interpreters.  This is a nit-pick, but you also don't have any separating specifiers between each VM name either (`,` after each value).

Comment: Hi any idea how i can get this array passed into the JSON

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that what you intend your output to be is actually this:

```
{
    "VMNames":  {
                    "value":  [
                                  "vmr1ssr1",
                                  "vmr1ssr2",
                                  "vmr1ssr3"
                              ]
                }
}
```

The difference being the comma after the name for each VM. The only change you have to make to your code is to expand the `Name` property, rather than just select it. As it stands you have the line:

```
$arrayvms = @(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $arrayRg  | ? {$_.Name -like "*$vms*"}) | select Name
```

This leaves you with 3 objects that have 1 property, `Name`. The value of that property is the relevant content here, so rather than just `Select Name` you want to use the `-ExpandProperty` parameter, changing that line to this:

```
$arrayvms = @(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $arrayRg  | ? {$_.Name -like "*$vms*"}) | select -expand Name
```

Now your JSON will look like what I have above.

**Edit:** If `-ExpandProperty` does not work you can have PowerShell loop through each object and output the property value with a `ForEach-Object` loop. I use the shorter alias of `%` here:

```
$arrayvms = @(Get-AzureRmVM -ResourceGroupName $arrayRg  | ? {$_.Name -like "*$vms*"}) | % Name
```

Comment: @themadtechbician thanks for that, I did actually try that, in my original post I mentioned trying -expandProperty however this didn’t work.. I’ll try with just -expand

Comment: `-expand` is just short for `-expandproperty`, and that should work. If it does not, try piping to `|% Name` instead of `|Select -Expand Name` to see if that works better for you.

Comment: Perfect, that works great, thanks. If you add that as an answer I'll accept it, thank you for your help  :)